# How union works when we print other variables which are not initialized?

Tags: c, constants, unions

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
union employee
{ 
    char name[15]; 
    int age; 
    float salary; 
};
const union employee e1; 
int main()
{ 
    strcpy(e1.name, "z");
    printf("%s %d %f\n", e1.name, e1.age, e1.salary);
    strcpy(e1.name, "x");
    printf("%s %d %f", e1.name, e1.age, e1.salary);
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
z 122 0.000000
x 120 0.000000
```

union is declared `const` but why the value is changing?
and how the union works when we print other values?

Comment: 1) Should not use `strcpy(e1.name, "z");` with `const union employee e1;` Is not your compiler complaining?  (or get a new compiler) 2) `printf("%s %d %f\n", ... , e1.age, e1.salary);` is UB.

Comment: but why the string is getting copied? @chux

Comment: Because you ignore compiler warnings. [edit:] Or using a C89 compiler and didn't include `<string.h>` (and still, the compiler could warn for the incompatible implicit declaration, and `gcc -std=c89` does)

Comment: Use -Wall and -Wextra and save everyone's time.

Comment: `union.c: In function ‘main’:
union.c:13:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
     strcpy(e1.name, "z");
     ^
In file included from union.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^`
getting this warning, so strcpy can copy to const variabls?

Comment: You violated a constraint (so you got a warning), a conforming implementation may refuse to compile (e.g. `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors` is such an implementation). Even if you cast `const` away, you have UB, some possibilities: 1. The object is placed in read-only memory and trying to write there causes a crash. 2. It behaves as in your case. 3. The compiler re-orders the `printf` statements and they give the same output, as the compiler knows the passed objects never change.

Comment: "getting this warning, so `strcpy` can [...]"--I don't understand the "so", how can you deduce from a warning that something works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to `const` data is undefined behavior (UB).

```
const union employee e1; 
strcpy(e1.name, "z");
```

You are "getting this warning, so strcpy" **may or may not** correctly perform the copy to a `const`.  Code has broken the contract about writing to `const` data.  Now the compiler not longer needs to behave in a proscribed manner.  The code may abruptly fail at this point or it may do anything - including work as desired.  That is undefined behavior (UB).